# Setup up a hierarchy from dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, hierarchy

I have a single CSV file of employees where I have employee data including the name, boss, department id and department name.
By reading that CSV file, I have created those 2 dict structures:

```
dep = {}
dep[1] = {'name': 'Sales', 'parent': None}
dep[2] = {'name': 'National Sales', 'parent': None}
dep[3] = {'name': 'International Sales', 'parent': None}
dep[4] = {'name': 'IT', 'parent': None}
dep[5] = {'name': 'Development', 'parent': None}
dep[6] = {'name': 'Support', 'parent': None}
dep[7] = {'name': 'Helpdesk', 'parent': None}
dep[8] = {'name': 'Desktop support', 'parent': None}
dep[9] = {'name': 'CEO', 'parent': None}

emp = {}
emp[1] = {'name': 'John', 'boss': None, 'dep': 9}
emp[2] = {'name': 'Jane', 'boss': 1, 'dep': 1}
emp[3] = {'name': 'Bob', 'boss': 2, 'dep': 1}
emp[4] = {'name': 'Clara', 'boss': 2, 'dep': 2}
emp[5] = {'name': 'George', 'boss': 3, 'dep': 2}
emp[6] = {'name': 'Steve', 'boss': 2, 'dep': 3}
emp[7] = {'name': 'Joe', 'boss': 1, 'dep': 4}
emp[8] = {'name': 'Peter', 'boss': 7, 'dep': 5}
emp[9] = {'name': 'Silvia', 'boss': 7, 'dep': 6}
emp[10] = {'name': 'Mike', 'boss': 9, 'dep': 7}
emp[11] = {'name': 'Lukas', 'boss': 10, 'dep': 7}
emp[12] = {'name': 'Attila', 'boss': 7, 'dep': 8}
emp[13] = {'name': 'Eva', 'boss': 12, 'dep': 8}
```

Out of this I have 2 tasks:

1. Create a hierarchy of departments. (basically fill the value of the
   parent key)
2. Display (list) all the departments and employees for a boss

Expected result for the point #2 would be (everybody working in sales):

```
employees = {1: (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)}
```

for everybody working in National Sales:

```
employees = {4: (5)}
```

and for everybody working in International Sales (Steve is the only one, nobody is working for him)):

```
employees = {6: None}
```

How to achieve this in a performant manner (I have to handle several thousands employees)?

EDIT:
This a (simplified) CSV file structure:

```
id;name;boss;dep_id;dep_name
    1;John;;9;CEO
    2;Jane;1;1;Sales
    3;Bob;2;1;Sales
    4;Clara;2;2;National Sales
    5;George;3;2;National Sales
    6;Steve;2;3;International Sales
    7;Joe;1;4;IT
    8;Peter;7;5;Development
    9;Silvia;7;6;Support
    10;Mike;9;7;Helpdesk
    11;Lukas;10;7;Helpdesk
    12;Attila;7;8;Desktop support
    13;Eva;12;8;Desktop support
```

Comment: 1. There is missing information, e.g., where are the parent departments stored. 2. A dictionary might be the wrong structure when your keys are an integer range, consider a list of structs, or a pandas dataframe. 3. What have you tried? What specific problems did you encounter. 4. Does it really need to be performant if it is a one-time operation?

Comment: There is no missing information. I have to build the department structure out of the employee CSV flat file. The only way to create the department hierarchy is by the the boss (a department leader is a person who's boss is not working in the same department as the actual employee

Comment: @kmac: As per 2: a dictionnary if IMHO the right structure as it creates one and only one entry per key. As per 3: I'm stuck. Of course I could go through the whole structure for each iteration but I'm looking for a faster (and more elegant) solution. As per 4: I have some thousands of concurrent users. I receive this file from the HR department several times per day. And while I'm building this structure (and after check whether the DB should be updated) this info is not available for the users. So it must be performant.

Comment: Do you have to use dicts? 'Cause dataframes could be a better approach...

Comment: @Helena: No, dict is not a must, but I guess the problem would be exactly the same if I would use a DF. (and I'm a bit more familial with the dicts and a dict is using less resources under the hood)

Comment: Fair. But since DF's act very similar to datasets and run considerably fast, they are better for a deeper analysis of large amount of data (principally with CSV). Not trying to force you to something, but I already had similar issues and using `pandas` was my salvation!

Comment: OK. Than could you give me the solution using pandas? :-) The problem remains the same. (fill the department structure and update the DB and list all employees working for a particular boss or list None if that specific employee is not a boss or doesn't have ans subordinate.

Comment: 1. I missed that ;) 2. The solution for dicts should be portable to dataframes, so it seems fine to start there. You should gain performance if you switch. 3. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself." That is why people will normally ask what you've tried, and we can suggest improvements. It's hard to guess which part is giving you trouble 4. I see, that is good information to add to the problem. Continued...

Comment: Task 1 pseudocode: `for e in employees: deps[e.dep].parent = emp[e.boss].dep`. Ignores error handling (no boss, conflicting parent already set).

Comment: Task 2 pseudocode: `for i,e in emp.iteritems(): dep[e].emps.append(i)`. This requires a few tweaks by you (e.g., adding an empty list called `emps` to each departments). I would encourage you to use more descriptive variable names, your colleagues will thank you ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, here is a solution using pandas. The file is mocked using your example data, and it should be plenty fast for only a few thousand entries.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

f = StringIO("""
id;name;boss;dep_id;dep_name
1;John;1;9;CEO
2;Jane;1;1;Sales
3;Bob;2;1;Sales
4;Clara;2;2;National Sales
5;George;3;2;National Sales
6;Steve;2;3;International Sales
7;Joe;1;4;IT
8;Peter;7;5;Development
9;Silvia;7;6;Support
10;Mike;9;7;Helpdesk
11;Lukas;10;7;Helpdesk
12;Attila;7;8;Desktop support
13;Eva;12;8;Desktop support
""")

# load data
employees = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', index_col=0)

### print a department ###
# Filter by department and print the names
print employees[employees.dep_id == 7].name

### build org hierarchy ###
# keep only one entry per department (assumes they share a boss)
org = employees[['boss', 'dep_id']].drop_duplicates('dep_id')
# follow the boss id to their department id
# note: the CEO is his own boss, to avoid special casing
org['parent'] = org.dep_id.loc[org['boss']].values
# reindex by department id, and keep only the parent column
# note: the index is like your dictionary key, access is optimized
org = org.set_index('dep_id')[['parent']]
print org
```

Comment: While this seems to answer to my question, use of pandas makes my live far more complicated as it should be (it interprets NaN values as float, string values as int, doesn't strip char values, etc.). And if I want to specify the required datatypes I get always TypeError: data type not understood error messages. And because there are datatype mismatches, I cannot do a comparison with the data coming from the database (i.e. I don't know if and what should be updated, etc...). So pandas is fine if you have only numerical data, but it gets very complicated as long as you have complex datatypes.

Comment: Yep, pandas adds some constraints in order to excel at certain tasks. The fact that the data is coming in as a csv is a good hint that pandas is the right choice (it excels at tabular data). The csv parser does let you specify data types and add custom NaN handling, though another option is to pre-process the csv to transform problematic fields. Metadata/versioning could be done outside of the data table itself.

Comment: In fact pandas gives me far more constraints than help. And the documentation, at least for me is not sufficient/straightforward (i.e. there is no description what kind of dtypes are accepted for read_csv as str is not one of them. etc, etc). Like the above mentioned "data type not understood" for strings or "Integer column has NA values" type of errors. So there is too much magic just for reading a simple, mainly str based CSV file. So finally I have ended up using plan dicts (in fact 8, because the main file contains data for 7 other master data tables), doing DB insert/update/delete tasks